# How can I set alignment for a ListItem in a DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, drop-down-menu, alignment, listitem

I have a DropDownList in my aspx file like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="MaxRec">
  <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>100</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>150</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Selected="True">200</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In Chrome it renders like this:

[image: DDL]

How can i set the alignment on all ListItems to be to the right so that values are properly aligned?
I tried setting style="text-align:right" on the DropDownList and on the ListItems but it doesn't have any effect.
I need a solution that also works on **Chrome**.

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following style will align the numbers as required but will move the drop down arrow to the left instead of the right.

Other than using this I assume the inability to right align select options may be a limitation in Chrome.

```
.drop-down-list
{
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: +1 Cool, it works but like you said it puts arrow on the other side, i hope there is a better solution though

Answer (score 3):

the below code works for me

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
          select.myDropDownList {
            text-align: right;
          }
        </style>
 </head>  


 <asp:DropDownList ID="myDropDownList" Runat="server" CssClass="myDropDownList">
   <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>100</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>150</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownlist>
```

Comment: @Shebin: This is what i said in the post i tried but it doesn't work in Chrome.