# How to right-align options in a DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, css, drop-down-menu, alignment

I'm trying to right-align the options of a DropDownList, but it doesn't seem to work.

HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="MyDDL">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1234"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="123"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="12345"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

CSS:

```
.MyDDL
{
    width:100px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

The CSS is being applied (the width of the DropDownList is increased to 100px), but the options inside remain left-aligned.

What's wrong here?

---

### Update

It works perfectly in Firefox!
Could this be an Internet Explorer issue?
I'm running IE11.

Comment: I think this link would help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938374/how-can-i-set-alignment-for-a-listitem-in-a-dropdownlist

Comment: does float:right;  have any effect?

Comment: @Ganesh, the first answer is an ugly hack (and it also moves the arrow to the left), while the second answer is exactly the same setting I'm using...

Comment: @voddy, it moves the *control* to the left side of the page; it doesn't affect at all the text inside it.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a good, cross-browser way to do this. The best solution would be to use the `dir` attribute or CSS `direction` attribute to align right-to-left:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="MyDDL" dir="rtl">
```

```
.MyDDL
{
    width:100px;
    direction:rtl;
}
```

But as you mentioned, this will cause the `select`'s arrow to move to the left. Otherwise, the only alternative I know of would be to set `text-align:right` as you've already done, but that seems to **only work in Firefox** (tested in IE8, Firefox 27 amd Chrome 33).